# How to read UTF metadata returned by PDFsharp?

Tags: pdf, metadata, pdfsharp

I am trying to read some metadata from a PDF file and I am using PDFsharp for this. Unfortunately it seems to return the creator as UTF.

```
var reader = PdfReader.Open("data.pdf");
var creator = reader.Info.Creator; // þÿ\0M\0i\0c\0r\0o\0s\0o\0f\0t\0®\0 \0W\0o\0r\0d\0 \02\00\01\03
```

When using iTextSharp it works fine, which shows it's not a problem of the file.

```
var reader = new PdfReader("data.pdf");
var creator = reader.Info["Creator"]; // Microsoft® Word 2013
```

How can I read the creator correctly with PDFsharp? Since it seems to be an encoding issue I have the impression it should be a relatively easy fix, but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you using the latest version 1.50.4845-RC2a? If so, would you provide the PDF file? BTW: Looks like UTF-16, not UTF-32.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with iText?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I tagged it as iTextSharp but it seems like stackOverflow has a problem of their own and only shows (or saves) iText even though I click on the suggested iTextSharp.

Comment: But did you intend iTextSharp or PdfSharp? Because they are unrelated products.

Comment: Please read my question first, Amedee. It's clearly stated I am experiencing the problem in PdfSharp and that I merely used iTextSharp for comparison purposes to ensure there is no problem in the PDF.

Comment: The problem is with PDFsharp and references to iText or iTextSharp are not needed, are they? An MCVE would be good. Too many unrelated tags are potentially harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate this behaviour with PDFsharp 1.32 from 2013.
I cannot replicate this behaviour with PDFsharp 1.50 from 2018. At some time in the past five years this issue has been fixed.

Use the latest version of PDFsharp and you can access the meta data as expected. Now that is a very easy fix. No bad idea to always try the latest version first when you encounter problems.

Comment: You're right. The thing is that Visual Studio is only showing PdfSharp Nuget v1.32.3057 (and indicates this is the latest stable version). I guess that is because 1.50 is only a RC for now. So I updated the PdfSharp version to 1.50.4845-RC2a through the Package Manager Console and this issue is fixed in the newer version. Sometimes the easiest solutions are the hardest to find!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 in the NuGet Package Manager you have to check the "Include prerelease" checkbox to see PDFsharp 1.50.